# Transform a data structure in go: panic: runtime error: index out of range

Tags: go

I have a data structure in go:

```
type APIMain struct {
    CodeConv string    `json:"codeConv"`
    Start    time.Time `json:"start"`
    End      time.Time `json:"end"`
    Details  []struct {
        IDPrm string `json:"idPrm"`
        Keys  []struct {
            Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
            Value     float64   `json:"value"`
        } `json:"keys"`
    } `json:"details"`
}
```

that I need to transform to:

```
type DataGroupedByTS struct {
    CodeConv string    `json:"codeConv"`
    Start    time.Time `json:"start"`
    End      time.Time `json:"end"`
    Details  []struct {
        Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
        Keys      []struct {
            IDPrm string  `json:"idPrm"`
            Value float64 `json:"value"`
        } `json:"keys"`
    } `json:"details"`
}
```

I get:

```
 panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

Here is my method but it is failing on the first line of loop:

```
func groupByTimestamp(apiMain datacheck.APIMain) DataGroupedByTS {
    var dataGrouped DataGroupedByTS
    dataGrouped.CodeConv = apiMain.CodeConv
    dataGrouped.Start = apiMain.Start
    dataGrouped.Start = apiMain.Start
    dataGrouped.End = apiMain.End

    var iDetail = 0
    var iKey = 0
    for _, detail := range apiMain.Details {
        for _, key := range detail.Keys {
            dataGrouped.Details[iDetail].Timestamp = key.Timestamp  // <-- failing here
            dataGrouped.Details[iDetail].Keys[iKey].IDPrm = detail.IDPrm
            dataGrouped.Details[iDetail].Keys[iKey].Value = key.Value
            iKey++
        }
        iDetail++
    }

    return dataGrouped
}
```

Basically, data originally comes grouped by `IDPrm`, and I need to group it by timestamp.

How should I do that ? Is there any helpers that could help doing it ?

Comment: You can simplify this a bit by moving `iDetail` and `iKey` into the for loop itself, e.g. `for iDetail, detail := range apiMain.Details`

Comment: As for the index out of range error, you're looping over apiMain.Details but accessing dataGrouped.Details which has not been set yet. Probably what you want is to make a new Details object and append it to dataGrouped.Details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

The reason is simple:

```golang
var dataGrouped DataGroupedByTS
```

initializes the fields of `dataGrouped` to the so-called
zero value for the type `DataGroupedByTS`.

The zero value of any compound type `T` consists of
the zero-values for types corresponding to each of the fields of `T`.

So, for

```golang
type DataGroupedByTS struct {
    CodeConv string    `json:"codeConv"`
    Start    time.Time `json:"start"`
    End      time.Time `json:"end"`
    Details  []struct {
        Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
        Keys      []struct {
            IDPrm string  `json:"idPrm"`
            Value float64 `json:"value"`
        } `json:"keys"`
    } `json:"details"`
}
```

the zero value would be

```golang
type DataGroupedByTS struct {
    CodeConv: "",
    Start:    time.Time(0),
    End:      time.Time(0),
    Details:  nil,           // watch this!
}
```

That's because the type of `Details` is `[]struct{ ... }`,
that is, a slice of some structs, and the zero-value of any slice is `nil`.

You then go on and attempt to write at some index into a non-existing slice (well, the slice without any backing array allocated to hold its data).
This reasonably fails with "panic: runtime error: index out of range": an unallocated slice has zero elements, so there is no element at index 0, and there is nothing to assign to.

### The fix

Two ways:

1. Preallocate the destination slice:

   ```golang
       var dataGrouped DataGroupedByTS
       // ...
       dataGrouped.Details = make([]struct{...}, len(apiMain.Details))
       for _, detail := range apiMain.Details {
       // ...
   ```
2. Append to a slice, rather than updating its elements in place:

   ```golang
       var dataGrouped DataGroupedByTS
       // ...
       for _, detail := range apiMain.Details {
           dataGrouped.Details = append(dataGrouped.Details, detail)
           // ...
   ```

   It's OK to `append` to a `nil` slice.

Answer (score -1):

My two cents: Could you please whether the object is null or not, because the panic error clearly says "index out of range", and also check for the lower and upper boundaries in the for loop.